# Отображение сайта на мобильном

Tags: html, bootstrap, css, javascript

Здравствуйте! Скажите пожалуйста, как в новой версии Twitter Bootstrap убрать линейное отображение на мобильных устройствах, и сделать чтобы в мобильных браузерах всё отображалось так же, как и на лэптопе?
Сайт kamrating.ru

Answer (score 1, accepted):

что вы имеете ввиду под линейным отображением?
если ресайз контейнеров со смещением контената то можно использовать сетку задавая в ней колонки с параметром xs 
а впрочем здесь все есть http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid